# How to return a 2D char in java?

Tags: java, arrays, char, geometry

The given public static :

```
public static char[][] punkt(char[][] zf, int x, int y, char z)
```

gets a drawing area zf, the geometric coordinates (x; y) and a "drawing pen" z. If the dot (x; y) is outside the drawing area, the method must return the unchanged zf ( that's the first issue I have), otherwise it replaces the entry in the zf field corresponding to (x; y) with the character z and returns the changed drawing area

I tried doing it this way but no matter what I try, I can't get it to return the unchanged "zf"

```
if (x > 79 || y > 39) {
 return char [][] zf;
} else //( here I should type that it should update zf with the new values of x,y and z then return)//
```

`system.out` and `Arrays.fill` are also not be used in this thing, only return statements :/

Comment: First: `return zf`. Second: if you change the contents of `zf` the caller of `punkt` will see those changes, be aware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When returning an array you only want to write `return zf;` without declaring a new array, do you also want a solution for your else-statement?

Edit: nvm I just add it:

```
if(something) {
    doSomething;
} else {
    zf[x][y] = z;
    return zf;
}
```

Or even better: (edited thanks to Eritrean)

```
if((x > 0 && x <= 79) && (y > 0 && y <= 39)) {
    zf[x][y] = z;
}
return zf;
```

Comment: Tried doing that earlier but it returned these errors:
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
 - Syntax error, insert ". class" to complete Expression
 - Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<char[]> to

EDIT : yes, I genuinely lost doing that else statement <3

Comment: Can you please add a little more context (code snippets) and/or the error messages

Comment: The second code worked flawlessly! very smooth, thank you very much for your input :)

Comment: You should also consider to add checks for negative values. These code will produce an IndexOutOfBound Exception for x<0 and y<0.